# Firefox 3.6 Kiosk mode

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, kiosk, firefox-3.6

I've developed a FF 3.6+ only web app that needs to run in kiosk mode. I has assumed that since nearly [every](http://www.ghacks.net/2009/06/23/internet-explorer-8-command-line-arguments/) [other](http://www.opera.com/support/mastering/kiosk/)  [browser](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=23145) has a built in kiosk switch FF would have this too. I haven't been able to find this.

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Command_line_arguments does not have a kiosk mode listed.

[R-Kiosk](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1659) doesn't work in FF 3.6. Apparently their is a new "experimental" version of R-Kiosk (v0.8.0) but I can't find it anywhere.

Does anyone know of anyway to put Firefox in kiosk mode?

I'd be especially great if the solution forced full screen, hid all toolbars and context menus, disables (Ctrl+) Alt + * combos, and disables "Windows Key" + * combos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's the [Full Fullscreen](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1568?src=api) add-on.

Doesn't restrict keyboard usage, but you can configure it to run full-screen on startup.